# complete missing element in magic square in java

Tags: java

I am creating a program to complete missing elements in 3*3 magic square. A magic square is a two-dimensional array *n * n*. In a magic square, the sum of each row is equal to sum of column, and is equal to the sum of diagonal. Also, all elements are unique.

This is an example:

```
2  7  6            2  7  6
9  0  0 ---------> 9  5  1 
0  0  0            4  3  8
```

this what I do:

```
import java.io.*;

    class asdf {
        public static void main (String[] args) {
            int sum = 0;
            int index = 0;
         int [][]arr = {
                 {12,17,10},
                 {11,0,0},
                 {0,0,0}
         } ;
            for (int i = 0;i<3;i++){
                sum += arr[index][i];
            }
         arr[2][0] = sum - (arr[0][0]+arr[1][0]);
          arr[1][1] = (arr[0][2]+arr[2][0])/2;
          arr[1][2] = sum-(arr[1][0]+arr[1][1]);
          arr[2][1] = sum - (arr[0][1]+arr[1][1]);
            arr[2][2] = sum - (arr[0][2]+arr[1][2]);
         for (int i = 0;i<3;i++){
             for (int j = 0;j<3;j++){
                 System.out.print(arr[i][j]+" ");
             }
             System.out.println();
         }
        }
    }
```

but I think this way of thinking is not efficient so what should I do?

Comment: You seem to be solving this one particular magic square. However, if the given inputs are in a different form, you'll have to find another way.

Answer (score 0):

Typically these kind of problems should be solved by backtracking but in case of magic square there is a specific pattern which can be implemented by playing with the indices. [Here](https://onlinegdb.com/S1xKahW1P) is the java program.

**n** : Size of the square matrix
**initial**: From which number magic square should start with(In your eg its 1)
**initialRow/initialCol** : From which position initial seed should start(In your eg its 1,2)

Following is the same program written in javascript

```js
var n=3;
var initial=1;
var initialRow = 1;
var initialCol = 2;
var a = [[]];


    
function computeMagicSquare(){
  var p = {}
  p.row = initialRow;
  p.col = initialCol
  for(let i=0;i<n;i++){
      for(let j=0;j<n;j++){
          choosePos(p);
        a[p.row][p.col] = initial++;
        
        p.row--;
        p.col++;
      }
  }
}
function choosePos(p){
  normalizePos(p);
  if(a[p.row][p.col]!=0){
    p.row++;
    p.col++;
    choosePos(p);
  }    
}
function normalizePos(p){
  if(p.row<0){
      p.row = n-1;
  } 
  if(p.col<0){
      p.col = n-1;
  }
  p.row = p.row%n;
  p.col = p.col%n;
}
function printArray(){
  let row;
  for(let i=0;i<n;i++){
    row = '';
    for(let j=0;j<n;j++){
     row+=a[i][j]+' ';
    }
    console.log(row);
  }
}
function initializeArray(){
  for(let i=0;i<n;i++){
         a[i]=[];
      for(let j=0;j<n;j++){
          a[i][j]=0;
      }
    }       
}  
if(n%2==0){
  console.log('n should be odd number');
} else {
  initializeArray();
  computeMagicSquare();
  printArray();
}
```